# How to add secondary y-axis to highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've recently started using highcharts javascript library and came across a situation where i'm supposed to add a secondary y-axis to the existing line chart. Here is an example from the highcharts website that is similar to the chart i'm working on ==>
[Line chart](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/)

What i'm trying to do is to add a 2nd y-axis to the right with color blue and with tick values 0, 1, 2 and 3 on alternate lines. This seems easy and tried in the following way but could not succeed

```
yAxis: [{
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: 'red'
                }]
            }, {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (F)'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: 'blue'
                }]
            }],
```

Pls guide me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 23, accepted):

See this [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.opposite) and this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/opposite/). Note you do not have to make the axis opposite the chart from each other. You can use offset for same-side axis.

The trick is you need a list of multiple axes settings, and the series needs to identify which zero-based axis it uses:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        marginRight: 80 // like left
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: [{
        lineWidth: 1,
        title: {
            text: 'Primary Axis'
        }
    }, {
        lineWidth: 1,
        opposite: true,
        title: {
            text: 'Secondary Axis'
        }
    }],

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
        yAxis: 1
    }]
});
```

(edits: Doc needs link to xAxis.opposite since yAxis.opposite is missing, added copy of jsfiddle code, added note about multiple axes.)

Comment: what does yAxis : 1 in series.data mean? Also how to change the left axis for the red line with 0, 50, 100, .., 250 and secondary axis for the blue line with 0, 1, 2, 3 (alternatively)

Comment: The yAxi: 1 tells the series which yAxis it is to plot against. For changing the values of the yAxis that would depend on the values in your series - I am not really following what you mean with that.